# PhoneGap config.xml not working in PhoneGap Build

Tags: phonegap-build

I initially created a web app (HTML, CSS, jQuery) without PhoneGap or Cordova. I used PhoneGap Build to build the app. Everything worked as expected.

However, I then installed PhoneGap, and adjusted my project's structure to work with PhoneGap. Now my `config.xml` file lives at the `root`, and the app lives in `www`.

I also used the `config.xml` file that PhoneGap creates when using the CLI, and removed the `config.xml` file I initially created when using PhoneGap Build's settings.

Since doing this, it seems that PhoneGap Build does not respect my `config.xml` file.

I've tried the following:

1. Adding the `config.xml` file to the `www` directory in addition to keeping it at the `root` level.
2. Only keeping the `config.xml` file in the `www` directory.
3. Using the original `config.xml` file I created with PhoneGap Build in both the `www` and `root` directories.

Also, I am running PhoneGap `5.0.0-0.28.1`. However, on PhoneGap Build it says I'm running `3.3.0`

Answer (score 1):

@Stephen, 
On the versioning, you are likely setting your Phonegap Build version in your config.xml.

The issue you have with the actual location of the config.xml is a bug. I recently added this to the [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/J6kWRdmtmIg). The bug is [#522](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/522). It appears your bug is a variation on this same bug.